# SQL - Update statement

Tags: sql

Hi
Suppose I have a table as below, I want to update the cat to 22 if **id > 2**, how can I write this statement?

Thanks

```
id    cat
----- -----
1     12
2     12
3     32
4     32
5     32
…     …
100   32
```

Comment: If I want to add one more condition: cat = 32, the sql should be "UPDATE table SET cat = 22 WHERE id > 2 && cat = 32"?

Comment: yes.. just you use AND and not &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update [tablename] set cat=22 where id > 2;

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET cat = 22 WHERE id > 2
```